# Creating user with password from variables in anonymous block

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I want to create a script that will have variables of `_user` and `_pass` to create the user in the Postgres database *only* if such login does not exist yet. I was thinking this would work, but i cant tell what is the issue:

```
DO
$DO$
DECLARE
  _user TEXT := 'myuser';
  _pass TEXT := 'user!pass';
BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM   pg_catalog.pg_roles WHERE  rolname = _user) THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'Creating user % ...',_user;
        CREATE USER _user WITH
            LOGIN
            NOSUPERUSER
            CREATEDB
            CREATEROLE
            NOREPLICATION
            PASSWORD _pass;

        RAISE NOTICE 'Created user %',_user;
   ELSE
        RAISE NOTICE 'User % already exists, not creating it',_user;
   END IF;
END
$DO$
```

How do I enforce substitution of the variable with its content?

Also what is the difference between `$DO$` and `$$`?

Comment: You need [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) for that

Comment: There is no difference between `$DO$` or `$$` or `$lkdazlkfdj$`, as long as you have a matching delimiter at the other end of the block: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To parameterize identifiers or syntax elements, you generally need to use dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE` - best combined with `format()` for ease of use.

But utility commands (incl. all SQL DDL statements) do not allow passing of values or parameter substitution *at all*. You need to concatenate the complete statement before executing it. See:

- [“ERROR: there is no parameter $1” in “EXECUTE .. USING ..;” statement in plpgsql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/121549/3684)

Your code would work like this:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
  _user text := 'myuser';
  _pass text := 'user!pass';
BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles WHERE rolname = _user) THEN
      EXECUTE format(
        'CREATE USER %I WITH
            LOGIN
            NOSUPERUSER
            CREATEDB
            CREATEROLE
            NOREPLICATION
            PASSWORD %L'
         , _user
         , _pass
         );
      RAISE NOTICE 'Created user "%"', _user;
   ELSE
      RAISE NOTICE 'User "%" already exists, not creating it', _user;
   END IF;
END
$do$
```

But while `_user` and `_pass` are hardcoded anyway, you might simplify like demonstrated here:

- [Create PostgreSQL ROLE (user) if it doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092086/create-postgresql-role-user-if-it-doesnt-exist/8099557#8099557)

> Also what is the difference between `$DO$` and `$$`?

See:

- [What are '$$' used for in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144284/what-are-used-for-in-pl-pgsql/12172353#12172353)

Answer (score 1):

Another way of ab(using) customized options ( quoting Erwin's older answers) :

- src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49175321/65706
- src: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/213921/1245
  which could enable the passing of the variables from bash script as well :

aka in bash:

```
  set -x
  PGPASSWORD="${postgres_db_useradmin_pw:-}" psql -q -t -X \
  -w -U "${postgres_db_useradmin:-}" \
  -h $postgres_db_host -p $postgres_db_port \
  -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 \
  -v postgres_db_user="${postgres_db_user:-}" \
  -v postgres_db_user_pw="${postgres_db_user_pw:-}" \
  -v postgres_db_name="${postgres_db_name:-}" \
  -f "$sql_script" "${postgres_db_name:-}" > "$tmp_log_file" 2>&1
```

and in pgsql

```
  SET myvars.postgres_db_user TO :'postgres_db_user';
  SET myvars.postgres_db_user_pw TO :'postgres_db_user_pw';

  DO
  $do$
  BEGIN
     EXECUTE format(
        'CREATE ROLE %I WITH PASSWORD %L LOGIN'
           , current_setting('myvars.postgres_db_user', true)::text
           , current_setting('myvars.postgres_db_user_pw', true)::text
     );
     RAISE NOTICE 'Created user "%"', 
  current_setting('myvars.postgres_db_user', true)::text;
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
     RAISE NOTICE 'User "%" already exists, not creating it',
     current_setting('myvars.postgres_db_user', true)::text;
     EXECUTE format(
        'ALTER ROLE %I WITH PASSWORD %L LOGIN'
           , current_setting('myvars.postgres_db_user', true)::text
           , current_setting('myvars.postgres_db_user_pw', true)::text
     );
  END
  $do$;
```

worth noting that often the same result might be achieved much more easier by means of a combination of bash vars interpolation and sql like this:
https://github.com/YordanGeorgiev/qto/blob/master/src/bash/qto/funcs/provision-db-admin.func.sh

Comment: The link provided is no longer available. @Yordan , could you please update it? It would be very useful to the community.