# set "VALID UNTIL" value with a calculated timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create user or change password with a timestamp calculated over current time.
example:

```
# CREATE USER user WITH PASSWORD 'password12345678' VALID UNTIL '(NOW() + interval 1 month)';
```

of course it's not valid:

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "(NOW() + interval 1 month)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utility commands like `CREATE USER` do not accept expressions, only literals. You need dynamic SQL.

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format($$CREATE USER myuser WITH PASSWORD 'password12345678' VALID UNTIL %L$$, NOW() + interval '1 month');
END
$do$;
```

Detailed explanation:

- [Creating user with password from variables in anonymous block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49169566/creating-user-with-password-from-variables-in-anonymous-block/49175321?r=SearchResults#49175321)

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with postgresql but from a quick google search it appears you want the following:

```
CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 month';
```

Comment: yes, but "VALID UNTIL" doesn't accept this kind of input. # CREATE USER cdb WITH PASSWORD 'password12345678' VALID UNTIL 'CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 month'';
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 1: ...rd12345678' VALID UNTIL 'CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 month'';