# How to substitute a variable when creating a check constraint?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql, check-constraints

I need to add a required field for newly added rows. However, it is undesirable to set the default value for old rows due to the large size of the table. I need to provide an automated script that will do this.
I tried this, but it does not work:

```sql
do $$
declare 
    max_id int8;
begin
    select max(id) into max_id from transactions;
    alter table transactions add constraint check_process_is_assigned check (id <= max_id or process_id is not null);
end $$;
```

Comment: The `id` is *always* less than or equal to the `max_id` (assuming it is not `null`).  What is the point of the logic?

Comment: What @GordonLinoff says and in addition from [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html): "Currently, CHECK expressions cannot contain subqueries nor refer to variables other than columns of the current row (see Section 5.4.1). The system column tableoid may be referenced, but not any other system column."

Comment: @Gordon: The point, AIUI, is to create a `CHECK` constraint that enforces `process_id IS NOT NULL` only for *future* rows (bigger IDs than the current maximum).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utility commands like `ALTER TABLE` do not accept parameters. Only the basic DML commands `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` do.
See:

- [set "VALID UNTIL" value with a calculated timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54482903/set-valid-until-value-with-a-calculated-timestamp/54486408#54486408)
- [“ERROR: there is no parameter $1” in “EXECUTE .. USING ..;” statement in plpgsql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/121549/3684)
- [Creating user with password from variables in anonymous block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49169566/creating-user-with-password-from-variables-in-anonymous-block/49175321#49175321)

You need **dynamic SQL** like:

```sql
DO
$do$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format(
     'ALTER TABLE transactions
      ADD CONSTRAINT check_process_is_assigned CHECK (id <= %s OR process_id IS NOT NULL)'
    , (SELECT max(id) FROM transactions)
   );
END
$do$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=124dbb9d744e5fd1e3a31f7af77e9821)*

This creates a `CHECK` constraint based on the *current* maximum `id`.

Maybe a [**`NOT VALID`** constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) would serve better? That is not checked against *existing rows*:

```sql
ALTER TABLE transactions
      ADD CONSTRAINT check_process_is_assigned CHECK (process_id IS NOT NULL) NOT VALID;
```

But you do have to "fix" old rows that get updated in this case. (I.e. assign a value to `process_id` if it was NULL so far.) See:

- [Enforce NOT NULL for set of columns with a CHECK constraint only for new rows](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/128154/3684)
- [Best way to populate a new column in a large table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/52531/3684)