# Use value from current_settings to establish postgres_fdw connection

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql, ddl, postgres-fdw

I am trying to set up a PostgreSQL Foreign Data Wrapper and to access the credentials from `current_settings` so that they are not hard-coded in my source code.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;
CREATE SERVER remote_server
  FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
    OPTIONS (
      host current_setting('db.REMOTE_DB_HOST'),
      port current_setting('db.REMOTE_DB_PORT'),
      dbname current_setting('db.REMOTE_DB_NAME')
    );
```

Before hand, I have set the credentials in as such:

```
SET db.REMOTE_DB_HOST='localhost';
SET db.REMOTE_DB_PORT='5432';
SET db.REMOTE_DB_NAME='remotedb';
```

Now, I can get the values without problem:

```
SELECT current_setting('db.REMOTE_DB_HOST') AS host, current_setting('db.REMOTE_DB_PORT') AS port, current_setting('db.REMOTE_DB_NAME') AS dbname;
```

yields the expected

```
   host    | port |  dbname 
-----------+------+----------
 localhost | 5432 | remotedb
```

But, when I try to establish the remote_server connection, I get the following error, without any other detail:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "current_setting"
> LINE 4:       host current_setting('db.REMOTE_DB_HOST'),
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DDL commands do not allow interpolation. You cannot execute commands inside the `CREATE SERVER` command, only pass literal constants. Concatenate the command string and execute it.

You can use dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE` in a `DO` command:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;  -- this works as is

DO                              -- dynamic SQL with EXECUTE
$$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('CREATE SERVER remote_server
                   FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
                   OPTIONS (host %L, port %L, dbname %L)'
                , current_setting('db.REMOTE_DB_HOST')
                , current_setting('db.REMOTE_DB_PORT')
                , current_setting('db.REMOTE_DB_NAME')
                 );
END
$$;
```

Related:

- [How to substitute a variable when creating a check constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911229/how-to-substitute-a-variable-when-creating-a-check-constraint/63911717#63911717)