# postgres create user only if not exists

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have few CREATE user  as part of  myquery.sql files and it contains few other queries as well

my file looks like this

```
CREATE USER myuser NOLOGIN;
GRANT CONNECT on DATABSE myDataBase to myuser;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEAMA myschema to myuser;
```

I have few queries like this in the same file,  due to some reason I  need to add new queries to same file, when execute the same file again I stuck with error user already exists, and does not reach to newly added query.

also I checked there is no IF NOT EXISTS kind of help for CREATE USER in postgres.

so how to add the check to create a USER only if not EXISTS.

Comment: Can you first drop the user ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create PostgreSQL ROLE (user) if it doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092086/create-postgresql-role-user-if-it-doesnt-exist)

Answer (score 6):

I don't know what you mean by "there is no `IF NOT EXISTS` kind of help for CREATE USER in postgres". A quick search yielded this, which will let you use plpgsql to do the check:

```sql
DO
$do$
BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT FROM pg_roles  
                   WHERE  rolname = 'my_user') THEN

      CREATE USER myuser NOLOGIN;
      GRANT CONNECT on DATABSE myDataBase to myuser;
      GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA myschema to myuser;
   END IF;
END
$do$;
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8099557/14443733). Optionally, you can [catch any exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092086/create-postgresql-role-user-if-it-doesnt-exist/49858797#49858797) of duplicate users so the remainder of your query runs smoothly, without any race conditions; there are even some bash alternatives even further down that thread.

> NB: You may need to use escape character for $ (like $) if you use
> the code block in a shell scripting.

Comment: `NOLOGIN` users are actually roles, so they will not have a row in `pg_shadow`. Select from `pg_roles` instead. And as you hinted, a race condition is possible in your code even after switching to `pg_roles`.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the tip @JonathanJacobson ; I'm not a Postgres person, just dabble when syntax lets me switch between rdbms.

Comment: This is pretty good already. Although you can instead use a BEGIN/END with a block to catch exceptions like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092086/create-postgresql-role-user-if-it-doesnt-exist#answer-38964044). It has the advantage of being safe in terms of race conditions.