# postgresql: Create user if not exit

Tags: sql, postgresql

Please is there a manner to create user if not exit.

```
CREATE USER sup_ WITH PASSWORD 'postgres';
```

When i executed two times got error saying that sup_ exist.
How should i do please to correct my query ?

Thank you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create PostgreSQL ROLE (user) if it doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092086/create-postgresql-role-user-if-it-doesnt-exist)

Answer (score 0):

There's no `IF NOT EXISTS` clause for `CREATE ROLE`.
You'll probably want to use PL/pgSQL to solve your problem. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092086/create-postgresql-role-user-if-it-doesnt-exist), it's basically the same one and the answers are really thorough.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether the user exists or not to avoid error. User below query:

```
Do
$do$
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM pg_user WHERE usename = 'sup_')then 
      CREATE USER sup_ WITH PASSWORD 'postgres';
   END IF;
end
$do$
```