# Syntax errors trying to create a user only if not exists in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, syntax-error, createuser

I'm trying to create a user in a PostgreSQL database only if it does not exist using the following:

```sql
SELECT 'CREATE USER konguser WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD kongpassword' 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_user WHERE usename = 'kongdb')\gexec
```

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "kongpassword"
> LINE 1: CREATE USER konguser WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD kongpassword
> ```

It still failed when using the password between `' '` or `" "`.
I also tried using the following:

```sql
DO
$$
BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT FROM pg_user
                   WHERE  usename = 'konguser') THEN

      CREATE USER konguser WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'kongpassword';
      GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE kongdb TO konguser;
      echo "test database & user successfully created"
   END IF;
END
$$;
```

With this result:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "168"
> LINE 2: 168
> ```

Comment: Error codes are only a way for your DB to return information to you about a query you just executed and it is a mistake to consider them a bad thing. For your case, you cannot **create** a user if a user/role with the same name already exists. Just execute `CREATE ROLE`/`CREATE USER` normally and check whether the [error code](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html) is 0 (`successful_completion`) or 42710 (`duplicate_object`).

Comment: Vote to reopen: the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092086/create-postgresql-role-user-if-it-doesnt-exist) this was marked as a duplicate of, fails the simple "Does this answer your question?" - OP was already attempting that, but what they needed clarifying were quoting rules and syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt is perfectly ok - only `"` are not the right quotes to use there and `'` probably matched with the ones you surrounded the query with. If you need to use `'` in a text literal, replace the outer single quotes with [double-dollar quotes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS): [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dH5PKNdz)

```sql
SELECT $q$CREATE USER konguser WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'kongpassword'; $q$ 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_user WHERE usename = 'konguser'))\gexec
```

Or escape it by duplicating it. Note that [`\gexec`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-GEXEC) only works the [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) client as an internal meta-command that won't work elsewhere. An  [`EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) in a procedural PL/pgSQL block can do the same, in any client:
:

```sql
DO $f$ BEGIN
EXECUTE (SELECT 'CREATE USER konguser WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD ''kongpassword'';'
         WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_user WHERE usename = 'konguser'));
END $f$;
```

Also, you were trying to create `konguser` under the condition that a `kongdb` user doesn't exist, which is a different user.

---

Your second attempt is perfectly valid as well, except the `echo`:

```sql
DO
$$
BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT FROM pg_user
                   WHERE  usename = 'konguser') THEN

      CREATE USER konguser WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'kongpassword';
      GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE kongdb TO konguser;
      --echo "test database & user successfully created"
      RAISE NOTICE 'test user successfully created';
   ELSE
      RAISE NOTICE 'test user already exists';
   END IF;
END
$$;
```

---

Depending on when this is supposed to be executed and why you're trying to emulate a **`if not exists`** clause for a `create user`, it's possible to do the opposite - make sure they don't:

```sql
DROP USER IF EXISTS konguser;
CREATE USER konguser WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'kongpassword';
```

Makes sense if you're (re)initialising something and you have full control over the user and everything that belonged to them. Note that it'd require you to first `REVOKE` those proviliges over `kongdb`.

Comment: Thanks ! the first method using the double quotes '' is ok

Comment: `SELECT 'CREATE USER konguser WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD ''kongpassword''; ' 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_user WHERE usename = 'konguser')\gexec`

Answer (score -1):

If you are new to psql and not familiar with the syntax there is another way to create username in psql db using pg admin.

Comment: this is scripted so i do not want to use pgadmin